# if statement perl, how to identify my chosen value

Tags: perl

I want to write down in Perl a code which should mean:

> `if a>0 or b>0 or c>0`, pick up the lowest value among those three and do stuff.

I am OK with the first part, which I coded as

```
if(a>=0 || b>=0 || c>=0) {
    # but here i don't know how to pick up the lowest value
}
```

How can I pick up the lowest value among those three?

Comment: `my ($min) = sort { $a <=> $b } $v1, $v2, $v3;` $a and $b are poor choices for variable names as they have special purpose for sorting.

Comment: Is it suppose to be `>0` or `>=0`?

Comment: Do you want to the minimum value of the three values, or do you want the minimum positive value of the three values?

Comment: I suggest to always use valid Perl in code snippets.  Here `a` isn't a variable, but `$a` would be.

Comment: Hey, sorry my mistake, i meant $a, it was just example though. Anyhow to answer ikegami  want to have the minimum positive value, so excluding 0, my fault.

Answer (score 3):

You asked for the minimum value of the three values (where `$min` could be zero or negative):

```
use List::Util qw( any min );

if (any { $_ > 0 } $a, $b, $c) {
   my $min = min $a, $b, $c;
   ...
}
```

But I think you meant to ask for the minimum positive value of the three values (where `$min` will always be greater than zero):

```
use List::Util qw( min );

my $min = min grep { $_ > 0 } $a, $b, $c;
if (defined($min)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: `sort` has been suggested, but `min` (O(N)) scales better than `sort` (O(N log N)), and is more self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a numerical [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) on the values after filtering them through [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to ensure the greater-than-zero condition is met:

```
my ($x, $y, $z) = qw(5 -1 2);

my ($min) = sort {$a <=> $b} grep {$_ > 0} ($x, $y, $z);

print "$min\n";
```

Output:

```
2
```

Note: The OP contradicts itself. In the opening sentence, it's greater-than, but in code, it's `>=`. I went with the former.